# Puppet fails with : Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)

Tags: ruby, linux, vagrant, puppet, unzip

#### Here is my puppet command:

```
exec { 'unzip Data.zip':
  command     => '/usr/bin/unzip -qq -o /vagrant/modules/wls/files/Data.zip -d /weblogic/app',
  group       => 'vagrant',
  user        => 'vagrant',
  require    => File['/weblogic/app/WEB-INF'],
}
```

#### Here is the error message:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Deploy_webapp/Exec[unzip Data.zip]/returns: change
>   from notrun to 0 failed: Cannot allocate memory - fork(2)

#### SLES 11SP3 on Virtual Box managed by Vagrant

- 1 Processor
- 4GB RAM ( works with 6GB )

  `# Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:`
  `vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]`

Comment: it's a linux problem not puppet. can you run ulimit -a on the machine ?

Comment: try "free -m" and check you have free swap

Comment: this is a `puppet` problem because this is apparently a `ruby` problem because the `unzip` command by itself has no issues, only when `exec` from inside `puppet`

Comment: there is plenty of free swap, it still fails unless I bump up the physical memory allocated to the VM, apparently ruby is a memory hog more than I thought.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286002/ruby-cannot-allocate-memory here is the answer

Answer (score 5):

Maybe overcommit is disabled in your system, try:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below, logstash start automatically after puppy agent -t command

systemctl stop logstash

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: You do realize that the question is six and a half years old, right?  The OP has surely long since moved on, and it is unclear whether the question is even still relevant to current Puppet. Anyway, although I could believe that this helps in some specific situations similar to the OP's, it hardly seems plausible as a general-purpose solution.  Also, "puppy"?