# Docket container exiting with 137 under relatively virtually no load, works well if there is load

Tags: java, docker

I have a docker container where i am running my java application using executable jar. Size for container i have set to **2 GB**, and java app **Heap memory is 1GB (-Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m)**. Every now and then my app gets exited with **exit code 137 (which is 128 + 9, i.e. docker manager is kill the container process since its using more memory then allocated)**.

**The logs does not say any OOM error (heap or meta space)**. I have NewRelic integration too, that also says the JVM metric are under control. (I know NR aggregate JVM metric every time but uploads every 1 minute, but i don't think app will take 300-400 MB memory in this 1 minute and before NR can report this increases, the container crashed)   [image: NR Heap memory metric when container exited] 
[image]

I did **docker inspect container id** and below is the response ("OOMKilled": true can see this)

```
[
{
    "Id": "85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069",
    "Created": "2018-03-09T22:08:23.220466103Z",
    "Path": "/bin/sh",
    "Args": [
        "-c",
        "exec java -javaagent:/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=${RUNENV} -jar -server -Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=16m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dspring.profiles.active=${RUNENV} ${APPNAME}-${SNAPSHOT}.jar",
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "[\"java\" \"-jar\" \"newrelic.jar\" \"install\"]"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": true,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 137,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2018-03-09T22:08:24.00385629Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2018-03-11T11:59:00.847375256Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:ffc04450b7b1c2df258210cf85b5183414db46562f819668958e3d6cbda64aef",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069/85f8dc2d2f18956e5fa0cb573e2f6f115348ffb1b6fa6c67a1c35cd0cf0fc069-json.log",
    "Name": "/prod_ats_1",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "prod_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8120/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "StorageOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 2147483648,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 4294967296,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "BlkioIOps": 0,
        "BlkioBps": 0,
        "SandboxSize": 0
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "devicemapper",
        "Data": {
            "DeviceId": "6652",
            "DeviceName": "docker-202:1-398151-e96af3795ec923bbdac4e2c7ff5e045e6985d94b2e36e05214fc3a71213eee59",
            "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
        }
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "85f8dc2d2f18",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8120/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk",
            "JAVA_VERSION=8u111",
            "JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.111.14-r0",
            "RUNENV=prod",
            "APPNAME=ats",
            "SNAPSHOT=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT=prod"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "[\"java\" \"-jar\" \"newrelic.jar\" \"install\"]"
        ],
        "Image": "nethum/ats:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-prod",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/app",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "exec java -javaagent:/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=${RUNENV} -jar -server -Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=16m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Dspring.profiles.active=${RUNENV} ${APPNAME}-${SNAPSHOT}.jar"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "6e1c97f2951d45feeb07eed99ea87734e65b5df6d52ab5f5e39eb31c77d66104",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "prod",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "ats",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.9.0"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "cd3792031b973869dba7178372f0cce8ed040486cf81a91d762d365fdcb96a53",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": null,
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cd3792031b97",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "prod_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "ats",
                    "85f8dc2d2f18"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "7d6ec63949a05c0122643a05aedf4b5ca114ecd9f9e71aaa6c7d80bb1c0ca2ff",
                "EndpointID": "",
                "Gateway": "",
                "IPAddress": "",
                "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": ""
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Docket stats show memory to 1.7GB immediately after starting the container.

```
**CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %  NET I/O               BLOCK I/O             PIDS**
85f8dc2d2f18          3.39%               1.594 GB / 2.147 GB   74.23% 556.6 kB / 660.9 kB   171.3 MB / 0 B        0
```

**i tried taking heap dump, but the process id it runs ( process id 1), i am not able to connect via JMX settings only**.

I have taken **thread dump via NewRelic**, but that does not shows any problem there.

i have hit dead end, and not sure how to debug this problem now and fix it.

I have setup **heap memory alert in New Relic** when usage reaches 80%, which i get 2-3 times a day, but this comes down after GC runs and app is not killed when this alert is raised.(Can related this in NR JVM metric section). When container gets killed, there is not heap memery usage alert before that.

This is **ps -aef output from inside the container**

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
1 root       8:40 java -javaagent:/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=prod -jar -server -Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150
181 root       0:00 sh
210 root       0:00 ps -aef
```

Few questions which is don't know the answer,

1. Is 2 GB container limit is enough if i have setup heap as 1 GB ?
2. How can i know what all process are running inside the container and how much memory each process is taking.
3. How can i check if there any other process inside the container which is taking up the memory and hence the container is getting killed ?

Comment: Check what's running with `docker exec $container ps -ef`.  The heap is only 1 component to memory usage, although generally the largest.  Does your app do any JNI calls or ProcessBuilder for child processes?

Comment: hi @matt, thanks for replying.  there is the output of command you asked for

/app # ps -af
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root     398:52 java -javaagent:/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=prod -jar -server -Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150
  899 root       0:00 sh
 1944 root       0:00 sh
 1950 root       0:00 ps -af

 Don't see any other process running. i am not sure about what you mean by "Does your app do any JNI calls or ProcessBuilder for child processes?"  What can i check for, to verify this ?

Comment: Could you edit the ps output into the original question so it can be code formatted? For newrelic, you would need to ask them but for `${APPNAME}-${SNAPSHOT}.jar` check the code it's built from.

Comment: @matt. Have updated the same. Code wise, it would not find any memory leak, also if there is memory leak, in logs i should have see OOM : Heap/Meta space issue, which is not coming in logs. So heap/Metaspace is not going beyond i have set. There is something else which is eating the memory. Need help to find that.

Comment: @Irathod It's likely memory usage outside the heap that Java can't OOM for. JNI code will allocate memory outside the heap. Running external processes will also use additional memory on top of Java. The same idea is covered in this [ruby question about external processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290263/1318694). If java still uses `fork` underneath then the container will need double the memory to run an external process.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1GB of memory is very little.  Also, set -Xmx and -Xms to be the same value.  That way when the JVM won't need to resize the heap at runtime and cause your program to crash
2. `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` and then you have a shell on the container.  Then you can `ps -ef` or whatever to find processes.  But surely your `Dockerfile` has a `FROM` declaration, you should know what to expect running.  Now you have a shell on the machine you can `jmap` a heap dump (if you're quick enough!)
3. `vmstat` is a good place to start analysing memory usage, swap and page ins/ outs.  `top` gives useful info as well.

Maybe you don't even need a 1GB heap.  Run `jmap -histo:live` to find the live objects size (these objects will most likely never be garbage collected).  An initial heap size about 3 or 4 times this will do as a starting point.  From then on, it's ideal if none of the new objects created on top of the live data objects ever get promoted to old gen...

Comment: Thanks for replying @paulturnip . One thing i noticed is, if i run the same app without docker, (directly as standalone executable jar), 1 GB memory seems to be enough. Also, i tried setting max and min heap same in non-production environment, but the pattern remains same. Since you also think the same, i will try to setting this in production environment as see if that helps. 

I will try other suggestion you gave and get back.

Thanks again for replying.

Comment: don't see any other process running inside container.

PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root     398:52 java -javaagent:/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.environment=prod -jar -server -Xmx1024m -Xss256k -Xms256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150
  899 root       0:00 sh
 1944 root       0:00 sh
 1950 root       0:00 ps -af

On taking thread dump using the process id , i get this "1: Unable to get pid of LinuxThreads manager thread" 

for same reason, i am not able to take head dump or use jmap -histo:live 1. 

docker stats output i have added in question.

Comment: @Irathod did you find any solution for this ? I also landed up in same situation.